# heroku run rake db:migrate fails to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Rails6 app to Heroku 
I'm able to successfully build  after pushing my app to Heroku but the app immediately crashes. 
I just added

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
end
```

to my Gemfile after developing in sqlite so I figured I'd need to migrate which brings me to my error

> peter.walker@MACSB-RJ2CLKF45C friends % heroku run rake db:migrate
> Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ ptw-friends... up, run.5761 (Free)
> Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.10

I'm not sure why I'm being told my Ruby version is 2.7.0.
My Gemfile has ruby '2.6.10', 
my Gemfile.lock has RUBY VERSION ruby 2.6.10p210, 
and my $ ruby -v returns ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [arm64-darwin21]

Could it be from adding

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rails s"
  },
```

to my package.json? 
Could I not be specifying the Ruby version in Procfile?

The full error is here along with my repo
https://github.com/petertimwalker/friends/issues/1

Comment: Have you tried doing what the very first warning is telling you? i.e. upgrade your version of bundler like it says: `gem install bundler:2.3.11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support all Ruby versions. When a Ruby version reaches end-of-life and is not maintained anymore then Heroku stops supporting it.

Ruby 2.6 reached end-of-life [December last year](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/).

Therefore you need to update your application and your local environment to at least 2.7 when you still want to be able to deploy on Heroku.

Please see the list of [Ruby versions supported by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions).

Answer (score 0):

install ruby version 2.6.10 and use that version in local
if you using rvm check your current version with `rvm list` and
install ruby 2.6.10 with `rvm install 2.6.10`
then  use command `rvm use 2.6.10`